# Definition of partial derivatives from Rudin's PMA

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

It's the definition of partial derivative from Rudin's PMA.

Why he consider $(25)$ for real functions $f_i$? What about if $f_i$ in $(25)$ replaced by vector-valued function $\mathbf{f}=(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m)$? I guess that it could be more general.

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can define the directional derivative of a vector-valued function. I'm guessing it's closely related to the total derivative.

Answer (score 3):

You can do linear algebra in terms of $n$-tuples $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ and matrices $\bigl[a_{ik}\bigr]$, or in terms of "abstract" vectors ${\bf x}$ and linear maps $A$.

Similarly with derivatives in a multivariate setting: You can consider component functions $f_i$ $(1\leq i\leq m)$ and their partial derivatives $f_{i.k}$, as defined in $(25)$, or you can talk about the derivative as a linear map between tangent spaces, and satisfying
$${\bf f}({\bf p}+{\bf X})-{\bf f}({\bf p})=d{\bf f}({\bf p}).{\bf X}+o\bigl(|{\bf X}|\bigr)\qquad({\bf X}\to{\bf 0})\ .$$
What you are proposing is a chimerical mixed version, which certainly  makes mathematical sense, but is only seldom used. At any rate, you would have
$${\bf f}_{.k}({\bf p})=d{\bf f}({\bf p}).{\bf e}_k\ .$$
(The dots have the following significance: In $d{\bf f}({\bf p}).{\bf X}$ I write a dot to enhance that one should first compute the derivative $d{\bf f}({\bf p})$ and then apply this linear map to the vector ${\bf X}$. Some people write $d{\bf f}_{\bf p}\,{\bf X}$ instead. In $f_{i.k}$ the $i$ denotes the $i^{\rm th}$ component of ${\bf f}$, and $k$ denotes the number of the variable with respect to which one differentiates. This then allows to write ${\bf f}_{.k}$ with the exact meaning the OP had in mind in his question.)

Comment: Nice answer. I've seen the definition in a few obscure texts but it doesn't seem to be of any geometric use.

Comment: Can you explain me some moments? You wrote $d{\bf f}({\bf p}).{\bf X}$  and ${\bf f}_{.k}({\bf p})$ but does mean the bottom dot above in these expreesions?

Comment: I would be very grateful if you expalin me my above question.

Comment: @RFZ I think Blatter has answered your question. He's simply talking about the total derivative of a function from $E\subset R^n$ to $R^m$. In this case, you can identify the tangent space $T_pE$ at $p$ with $E$. By the dot he means matrix multiplication. The ${\bf e}_k$ is just the standard basis for $R^n$.

Comment: @OliverJones, If by dot he means matrix multiplication then what does mean ${\bf f}_{.k}({\bf p})$? I guess that this notation is meaningless

Comment: @RFZ Isn't $${\bf f}_k({\bf p})=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{{\bf f}({\bf x}+t{\bf e}_k)-{\bf f}({\bf x})}{t}?$$

Comment: @OliverJones, Yes I am totally agree with that. But Blatter put "dot" in index of ${\bf f}_k({\bf p})$

Comment: @RFZ I'm not sure I follow you. If you substitute ${\bf X}={\bf e}_k$ into his first equation, don't you get the second?

Comment: @RFZ In my comment above, I think I need ${\bf p}$, not  ${\bf x}$.

Comment: @OliverJones, What is the difference between ${\bf f}_{.k}({\bf p})$ and ${\bf f}_{k}({\bf p})$? I can't understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35401/discussion-between-oliver-jones-and-rfz).

Comment: @RFZ I see what you mean! I didn't see the dot in ${\bf f}_{\cdot k}({\bf p})$. I have no idea what he means. Is that a typo?

Comment: @OliverJones, Yes it's exactly what did I mean. I have any idea what is it

Comment: @RFZ Does the formula make sense without it?

Comment: I guess that formula also holds without this "dot". Am I right?

Comment: @RFZ I think it does for the reason I gave above. But I don't think this generalization is very useful.

Comment: @OliverJones, Let's talk in chat?